# backref and natbib generating an error

Tags: hyperref, natbib, backref

For some reason since a few weeks ago, when I use both `natbib` and `backref`, I get an error message and compilation stops.

> ```
>   Runaway argument?
>   ! File ended while scanning use of \BR@@lbibitem.
> ```

I provide below a MWE. If the line with the `backref` package is commented out, the document does compile with MiKTeX in Windows 7 or Windows 10. When investigating, I noted that the `bbl` file has commented lines between the items in the reference list. I understand that for `backref` to work, there must be a blank line between two consecutive references in the `bbl` file.

How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib} %citep and citet
\usepackage[english,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@Article{boiral_2006,
  author    = {Olivier Boiral},
  title     = {Global Warming: Should Companies Adopt a Proactive        Strategy?},
  journal   = {Long Range Planning},
  year      = {2006},
  volume    = {39},
  number    = {3},
  month     = {jun},
  pages     = {315--330},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.lrp.2006.07.002},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  }

@Article{koe1,
  author  = {G. {K\oe nig}},
  title   = {Production de la connaissance et pratiques   organisationnelles},
  journal = {Revue de Gestion des Ressources Humaines}, 
  year    = {1993},
 volume  = {9},
  pages   = {4-17},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Minimum working example where the reference list is unable to correctly     backreference the citations.

K\oe ning
\cite{koe1}
\cite{boiral_2006}

\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for me your used `\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-harv}` is the culprit.

If I change it to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` I can compile your code without errors. Are you forced to use this style `elsarticle-harv`?

MWE (please see that I used option `[backref=page]` for package `hyperref` instead of calling package `backref`; language `english` is default):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{boiral_2006,
  author    = {Olivier Boiral},
  title     = {Global Warming: Should Companies Adopt a Proactive Strategy?},
  journal   = {Long Range Planning},
  year      = {2006},
  volume    = {39},
  number    = {3},
  month     = {jun},
  pages     = {315--330},
  doi       = {10.1016/j.lrp.2006.07.002},
  publisher = {Elsevier {BV}},
  }

@Article{koe1,
  author  = {G. {K\oe nig}},
  title   = {Production de la connaissance et pratiques organisationnelles},
  journal = {Revue de Gestion des Ressources Humaines}, 
  year    = {1993},
  volume  = {9},
  pages   = {4-17},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage[english,hyperpageref]{backref}
\usepackage{natbib} %citep and citet
\usepackage[backref=page]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
Minimum working example where the reference list is unable to correctly 
backreference the citations.

K\oe ning
\cite{koe1}
\cite{boiral_2006}

\section{References}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % elsarticle-harv <========================
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

with the following resulting pdf without errors or warnings:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this insight! I do have to use the Elsevier template as I am submitting to an Elsevier journal, but at least I can now ask them to modify their template.